# Convert JSON Array to Int Array In Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

This may be a silly question, but despite digging through the questions here on StackOverflow, I can't seem to find a use case that matches my predicament.

Namely, I have some data being pulled from a REST service that spits out some historical data as JSON;

```
[
    {
    "city": "New York",
    "historicalTemps": "98.46,71.81,76.58,82.38,91.08",
    "timestamp": "2015-06-04 10:20:34",
    }
]
```

I am able to parse my data in my iOS app, and am setting historicalTemps to a String.  Where I'm failing, however, is figuring out how to convert this comma-separated string to an Int array so it can populate my graph.  This is where I've stalled;

```
var arr = historicalTemps.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
println(arr)
//Prints [98.46,71.81,76.58,82.38,91.08] as I would want.
```

My attempts to figure out how to convert this String array to an Int array, however, are failing me.  Any possible suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure you mean 'Int array' judging by what you've said you want the output to be? An `Int` is a whole number, therefore you couldn't have a decimal point...

Comment: If at all possible, you should modify the response sent by the API. JSON should represent this information by having `historicalTemps` be an array of numbers instead of a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let str = "98.46,71.81,76.58,82.38,91.08"
let arr = split(str) { $0 == "," }
let nums = map(arr) { ($0 as NSString).doubleValue }

println(nums) // [98.46, 71.81, 76.58, 82.38, 91.08]
```

Comment: This has gotten me closer than ever before @ABakerSmith!  Thank you!  I changed your `$0.doubleValue` to `$0.integerValue`, which properly set the array as an [Int].  Sadly, now, the app is crashing when I try to render my graph, though manually setting `var graphPoints = [98.46, 71.81, 76.58, 82.38, 91.08]` will render the graph.  Something about setting `var graphPoints = nums` confuses the graph.  Well...thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer a little, I don't know if that will make any difference...but it's worth a try. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: `Assertion failed: (CGFloatIsValid(x) && CGFloatIsValid(y)), function void CGPathMoveToPoint(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat), file Paths/CGPath.cc, line 254.`  Admittedly, much of this code was based off of a tutorial, so it may be overly specific in what it's looking for.  I'll keep at it!

Comment: Got it working.  Turns out that the graph is unable to render if the array is something like [0,0,0,0,0].  I changed any instance of "0" to "1" since it works fine for the purpose of this test, and things are working properly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`componentsSeparatedByString` is a NSArray method. Thus, all you need do is call `.intValue` to get the integer representation of the string.

**Note that you need to call `.intValue` for every element of the array.**

Comment: Thanks, Kelvin!  I had been playing around with the `.toInt()` method, but I can't quite figure out the syntax of how I would do it, and what I would do with the output, even if I converted every element in the array to an Integer.  For example, I tried; `for i in arr {
                i.toInt()
            }` but then became confused as to where I'd go from there.  Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @Alan Lewis Actually I recalled incorrectly. The correct way is to call `.intValue`. Fixing answer